# wordpress sort by custom field

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I hope someone can help me with this. I have been reading other posts, the Codex, and trying others code, but can't fix my query.

I am creating a Page that contains a list of authors. The authors are in two categories, and I need to sort by last name, first name. I want to sort them by the custom field wpcf-sortname  (from the Types plugin).

I get the correct results from the query, but the results are sorted by ID.

Note: I'm not very good with queries, but any help will be appreciated.

I've tried:

```
<?php query_posts(array('category__and'=>array(48,49),'meta_key'=>wpcf-sortname,'orderby'=>meta_value,'order'=>ASC,));

if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="participants"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

And:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'category__and'=>array(48,49),'meta_key'=>wpcf-sortname,'orderby'=>wpcf-sortname,'order'=>ASC,'posts_per_page'=>-1);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
<div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="participants" style="color:red"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
<?php query_posts(array('category__and'=>array(48,49),'meta_key'=>'wpcf-sortname','orderby'=>'meta_value','order'=>ASC,));if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="participants"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br /><?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

I have just put the single quote in metakey and orderby field. I think this will work for you.

Comment: All my data is being sorted in the right order now! However, I am noticing a weird issue that for some reason one of the author's names doesn't appear. It only occurs in one category. Any idea why? `<?php query_posts(array('category__and'=>array(48,37),'meta_key'=>'wpcf-sortname','orderby'=>'meta_value','order'=>ASC,));if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="participants"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br /><?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>`

Comment: Just figured out why, looks like if I don't have the custom field filled out, the post doesn't show.